# When I click "enable secure and erase" in Find My device it says "request sent", but nothing happens

Tags: security, remote-control, remote-access, remote-wipe

I'm trying to enable remote locking and wiping for a phone. When I go to https://www.google.com/android/find  and click on “enable secure and erase” then it says "request sent", but I see nothing on the phone, no notification.

The strange thing is I can ring the phone via the web interface, so it reaches the phone, but I cannot enable lock and wipe, because I get no notification on the phone after "request sent". Why can this be?

[image]

Comment: Is *find my device* enabled in device administrator apps? Search your settings for device administrator

Comment: @beeshyams  yes, find my device is in device administrators and enabled

Comment: Obvious but asking - is your phone connected to Internet?

Comment: @beeshyams yes. I mentioned in the question that pressing the "play sound" button on the web interface does make the phone ring and there is even a notification then on the phone saying "find my device found your device". So there is a connection from the web, ringing works, but pressing the "enable&secure" button does not bring up a notification on the phone.